# Ansible how to remove groups value by key

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

I am having a play where i will collect available host names before running a task, i am using this for a purpose,

My play code:

```
    --
    - name: check reachable side A hosts
      hosts: ????ha???
      connection: local
      gather_facts: no
      roles:
        - Juniper.junos
      vars:
        credentials:
          host: "{{ loopback_v4 }}"
          username: "test"
          ssh_keyfile: "/id_rsa"
          port: "{{ port }}"
          timeout: 60
      tasks:
        - block:
          - name: "Check netconf connectivity with switches"
            juniper_junos_ping:
              provider: "{{ credentials }}"
              dest: "{{ loopback_v4 }}"
          - name: Add devices with connectivity to the "reachable" group
            group_by:
              key: "reachable_other_pairs"
          rescue:
            - debug: msg="Cannot ping to {{inventory_hostname}}. Skipping OS Install"
```

When i print this using

```
- debug:
      msg: "group: {{ groups['reachable_other_pairs'] }}"
```

i am getting  below result

```
"this group : ['testha1', 'testha2', 'testha3']",
```

Now if again call the same play with different hosts grouping with the same key i am getting the new host names appending to the existing values, like below

```
- name: check reachable side B hosts
  hosts: ????hb???
  connection: local
      gather_facts: no
      roles:
        - Juniper.junos
      vars:
        credentials:
          host: "{{ loopback_v4 }}"
          username: "test"
          ssh_keyfile: "/id_rsa"
          port: "{{ port }}"
          timeout: 60
  tasks:
    - block:
      - name: "Check netconf connectivity with switches"
        juniper_junos_ping:
          provider: "{{ credentials }}"
          dest: "{{ loopback_v4 }}"
      - name: Add devices with connectivity to the "reachable" group
        group_by:
          key: "reachable_other_pairs"
      rescue:
        - debug: msg="Cannot ping to {{inventory_hostname}}. Skipping OS Install"
```

if i print the reachable_other_pairs i am getting below results

```
"msg": " new group: ['testhb1', 'testhb2', 'testhb3', 'testha1', 'testha2', 'testha3']"
```

All i want is only first 3 entries `['testhb1', 'testhb2', 'testhb3']`

Can some one let me know how to achieve this?

Comment: Try to add `- meta: refresh_inventory` as a task just before your block. This will refresh your inventory and might clean up that group.

Comment: And let me know if it worked ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this as as task just before your block. It will refresh your inventory and clean up all groups that are not in there:

```yaml
- meta: refresh_inventory
```